# Python keyword in dict

Tags: python

I'm working with the telegram api and wanted to get the ID from the user but then I found out that one of the words is an python keyword. How to fix this?

```
f"{update.message.from.id}"
```

from
^^^^

Comment: @eatmeimadanish Why not just do what the answer in the duplicate says?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish No idea what you mean. They aren't in control of that here, either, are they? And the duplicate question is about the exact same thing.